# Statistical test to compare paired distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing

I have an experiment in which I am measuring the duration of "events" in the brain signal of several animals. Each animal is recorded under two conditions (say A and B). In each recorded session, I have between 100 and 150 events.

I would like to answer the two following questions :

- Is there a difference (at the population level) in the distributions of durations between condition A and condition B?
- If there is a difference, which part of the support of the distributions (so which durations) is showing a difference between condition A and condition B?

Any idea how to answer these questions in a statistically correct way? Any good reference to understand how to answer these questions?